# Какой подобрать синоним к словосочетанию "разве что"?

Tags: стилистика

"Такое количество книг она могла видеть разве что в замке". Можно ли заменить "разве что" на "возможно что"? "Такое количество книг она могла видеть возможно что (возможно что только) в замке?" Как при этом будут стоять запятые? Встречались ли вам подобные обороты в литературе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частицы недостатка, как: лишь, только, исключительно — близки по значению:
... могла видеть только в замке.
... могла видеть лишь в замке.
... могла видеть исключительно в замке.
Но при их использовании теряется элемент, что человек догадывается до этого. Этот элемент сохраняется у сочетания ‟если только”. ***Такое количество книг она могла видеть если только в замке.*** Запятые никак не будут ставиться, потому что такие сочетания являются частицами.

Comment: Спасибо, а если сказать со словом "возможно", как у меня в вопросе? Кажется, будто тоже слышала такое выражение...

Comment: Нет, такого сочетания в языке нет. Можно вставить вводное ‟возможно” на этом месте, и получится: ‟Такое количество книг она могла видеть, возможно, в замке". Если такой вариант подходит, то пожалуйста, можете использовать.